# why angular gives the injector module error?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

why when the view is rendered the following error was thrown

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   registrationModule due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
>   $routeProvider
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider
>       at http://localhost:2044/Scripts/angular.js:68:12
>       at http://localhost:2044/Scripts/angular.js:4397:19
>       at getService (http://localhost:2044/Scripts/angular.js:4550:39)
>       at injectionArgs (http://localhost:2044/Scripts/angular.js:4574:58)
>       at Object.invoke (http://localhost:2044/Scripts/angular.js:4596:18)
>       at runInvokeQueue (http://localhost:2044/Scripts/angular.js:4497:35)
>       at http://localhost:2044/Scripts/angular.js:4506:11
>       at forEach (http://localhost:2044/Scripts/angular.js:321:20)
>       at loadModules (http://localhost:2044/Scripts/angular.js:4487:5)
>       at createInjector (http://localhost:2044/Scripts/angular.js:4409:19)
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=registrationModule&…jector%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A2044%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A4409%3A19)

here is my `route configuration`

```
var registrationModule = angular.module("registrationModule", [])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Courses', { templateUrl: '/templates/courses.html', controller: 'CoursesController' });
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Instructors', { templateUrl: '/templates/instructors.html', controller: 'InstructorsController' });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

i'm using **Angular JS in MVC5**

Comment: Have you included the angular router JS?

Comment: @SatejS have added the module to the layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need include 'ngRoute'.

```
var registrationModule = angular.module("registrationModule", ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Courses', { templateUrl: '/templates/courses.html', controller: 'CoursesController' });
        $routeProvider.when('/Registration/Instructors', { templateUrl: '/templates/instructors.html', controller: 'InstructorsController' });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```